# Using pip freeze > requirements.txt will copy the libraries specific to that directory?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and noticed some unfamiliar libraries that were added to the requirements file. Does `pip freeze` only capture the libraries and dependencies that are specific to that directory or from the entire system?

Comment: even if you are inside virtual environment there is a chance you have installed libraries with dependencies that were installed with them

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you have noticed, [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/) doesn't capture the libraries specific to a directory but indeed all the package installed in the current environment (most likely the packages installed on your system or, if you are in a virtual environment without global access, those from that virtual environment).

You can try `pip freeze` from an other directory an see that you are having the same results.

If you want to obtain the list of dependency packages for a specific project you might be interested in the [`pipreqs` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipreqs) which precisely do that.

Comment: Thx for the hint with `pipreqs`!

Comment: Best to create a new virtual environment, install packages there and then use `pip freeze`. You can delete the venv after that